# Connect with tmux instead of screen

Tags: usb, screen, input-device, macos, modem

New questioner here! I am able to connect to my device using the following command:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbmodem* 115200
```

My device is connected to my Mac with a microUSB -> USB cable.

Is there a way that I can connect in the same way, but through `tmux` instead of `screen`?

Comment: where is the Raspberry Pi part of the question?

Comment: The device is a Raspberry Pi. My original phrasing was for Jetson Nano (that's what I'm tinkering with at the moment) but the exact same question applies to my Pi since I can connect it the same way

Comment: if it applies to multiple devices, then it is not about the devices ... your question is about the Mac, not about RPi

Comment: Tmux does not provide this feature. If you want to use tmux on your desktop PC / MAC just start it. From within it, you can start the connection to the raspi using e.g. minicom. To me it makes more sense to open a connection to the RASPI with e.g Minicom and then start tmux on the raspi itself. Then you also don't loose active sessions if the connection to the RasPi is closed. Using screen the way you did, looks like your sessions are save if the connection is closed, but that's not the case. This feature of screen is (IMHO) not a great advantage. Perhaps that's why tmux don't have it.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer your comment looks like a reasonable answer. Would you care to post it as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmux doesn't include a serial comms options however..  You con Pi's like the zero configure the USB port as a USB ethernet gadget and then ssh to the RPI0 via the USB cable.  Then run tmux as you would on any remote host.

https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget